# Does control on the “magnitude” of the rearrangement give control of the rearranged Cesaro sums?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a nonnegative sequence that Cesaro converges to $K > 0$. We recall this means

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 1}^N a_n \to K$$

as $N \to \infty$.

Suppose $a_{\phi_n}$ with $\phi: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is a rearrangement of the $a_n$ such that for some $\varepsilon > 0$, we have

$$|\phi(n) - n| \leq \varepsilon n$$

for all $n \in \mathbb N.$

Is it true that there exists some $C_\varepsilon$ depending only on $\varepsilon$ (and not $a_n$ or $K$) with $C_\varepsilon \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$ such that the partial averages of $a_{\phi_n}$ satisfy

$$(1-C_\varepsilon) K \leq \liminf_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n} \ \leq \limsup_{N \to \infty}  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n} \ \leq (1 + C_\varepsilon)K?$$

Comment: Do you also assume that $a_n\ge 0$? (otherwise the answer to the question as posed is trivially "No").

Comment: We do, yes sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$We have $\{\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{N-1}\}\subseteq\{0,\dots,\lfloor(N-1)(1+\ep)\rfloor\}$. Therefore and because $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n}\le \sum_{0\le n\le(N-1)(1+\ep)} a_n.$$
So,
$$\limsup_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n} \le (1+\ep)K.$$

Similarly,
$$\{\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{N-1}\}\supseteq\{0,\dots,\lfloor(N-1)(1-\ep)\rfloor\}; \tag{1}\label{1}$$
see details on this at the end of this answer.
Therefore and because $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n}\ge \sum_{0\le n\le(N-1)(1-\ep)} a_n.$$
So,
$$\liminf_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n} \ge (1-\ep)K.$$

**Details on \eqref{1}:** We have $|\phi_n-n|\le\ep n$ for all $n$, which can be rewritten as $|k-\psi_k|\le\ep\psi_k$ for all $k$, where $\psi$ is the inverse of $\phi$, so that $\phi_{\psi_k}=k$ for all $k$. So, $\psi_k\le\dfrac k{1-\ep}$ for all $k$. So, if $k\le (1-\ep)(N-1)$, then $\psi_k\le N-1$. That is, $\{\psi_0,\dots,\psi_{\lfloor(N-1)(1-\ep)\rfloor}\}\subseteq\{0,\dots,N-1\}$. That is, $\{0,\dots,\lfloor(N-1)(1-\ep)\rfloor\}\subseteq\{\phi_0,\dots,\phi_{N-1}\}$, so that \eqref{1} holds.

Comment: Nice! Any ideas on the liminf?

Comment: Ah yes it does follow similarly..

Comment: Thank you for the additional details, yes I agree it is true.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$This is to answer the question in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448971/does-control-on-the-magnitude-of-the-rearrangement-give-control-of-the-rearran/448973#comment1160141_448971) (now deleted) about whether the condition  that the $a_n$'s are $\ge0$ can be dropped.

It cannot. E.g., let $a_n:=1+(-1)^n\sqrt n$, so that
\begin{equation*}
    S_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n=N+(0-\sqrt1)+(\sqrt2-\sqrt3)+\cdots+(-1)^N\sqrt N=N+O(\sqrt N) 
\end{equation*}
and hence $K=\lim_N\dfrac{S_N}N=1>0$.

For natural $j$, let $E_j:=\{2^j,\dots,2^{j+1}-1\}$ and $F_j:=\{n\in E_j\colon n<2^j+2K_j\}$, for an integer $K_j<\ep 2^j$ such that $K_j\sim\ep 2^j$ (as $j\to\infty$). For each $j$, each $n\in F_j$, and $m:=n-2^j$, let
\begin{equation*}
    \phi_n:=
        \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
    2^j+2m&\text{ if } m<K_j, \\ 
    2^j+2m+1-2K_j&\text{ if } m\ge K_j. 
    \end{aligned} 
    \right. \tag{05}\label{05}
\end{equation*}
If $n$ is a natural number such that $n\notin F_j$ for any $j$, let $\phi_n:=n$. Note that (i) $\phi_n\in F_j$ if $n\in F_j$ and (ii) $\phi_\cdot$ is bijective on $F_j$, for each $j$. Since the $F_j$'s are disjoint, we see that $\phi_\cdot$ is a rearrangement of the natural numbers, satisfying the condition $|\phi_n-n|\le\ep n$ for all $n$.

Moreover, for $n\in F_j$ with $m<K_j$ we have $a_{\phi_n}=a_{2^j+2m}=1+\sqrt{2^j+2m}\ge2^{j/2}$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{n = 0}^{{2^j+K_j-1}} a_{\phi_n}=
    \sum_{n = 0}^{{2^j-1}} a_{\phi_n}+\sum_{n = 2^j}^{{2^j+K_j-1}} a_{\phi_n}
    \ge 2^j(1-o(1))+K_j 2^{j/2}\sim\ep (2^j)^{3/2}, 
\end{equation*}
whence
\begin{equation*}
    \limsup_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n}=\infty. \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}

A rather straightforward modification of this example will give
\begin{equation*}
    \liminf_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\,\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} a_{\phi_n}=-\infty. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
This is achieved by switching from the even-first pattern to the odd-first pattern, that is, by interchanging $m<K_j$ and $m\ge K_j$ in the definition \eqref{05} of $\phi_n$.

Another straightforward modification of this example -- by alternating (in $j$) the even-first pattern with the odd-first pattern -- will give both \eqref{10} and \eqref{20} simultaneously. $\quad\Box$

Comment: I have fixed and undeleted this answer.

Comment: Much appreciated, I had the same example in mind as well.